# Getting a element in a structure array

Tags: c++

This program choose any bin of same number of parts from 10 bins. When the program chose one, it ask if we want to either add or remove parts from that specific bin. How can I get a element from the structure array.
     //Structure
     struct Inventory
    {

```
   char description[35];
   int num;
 };

 //Function Prototypes.

 void choiceMenu(Inventory[], int);
 void AddParts(Inventory[], int);
 void RemoveParts(Inventory[]);

 int main()
 {
   char election;
   int choice;

   const int Number_Bins = 10;
    Inventory parts[Number_Bins] = {
                                  {"Valve", 10},
                                  {"Bearing", 5},
                                  {"Bushing", 15},
                                  {"Coupling", 21},
                                  {"Flange", 7},
                                  {"Gear", 5},
                                  {"Gear Housing", 5},
                                  {"Vacuum Gripper", 25},
                                  {"Cable", 18},
                                  {"Rod", 12}
                                  };
```

Is there other way to do it without putting the elements of the arrays from 0 to 9. like trying to do it with a accumulator. how can I take a specific element from the array.

```
 void choiceMenu(Inventory bin[], int z)
{


   cout << "                               Inventoy Bins\n";
   cout << "                              = = = = = = = = \n";
   cout << " *Choose the part of your preference.\n";
   cout << " 1. Valve" << bin[0].num << endl;
   cout << " 2. Bearing. Currently Number of Bearing = " << bin[1].num << endl;
   cout << " 3. Bushing. Currently Number of Bushing = " << bin[2].num << endl;
   cout << " 4. Coupling. Currently Number of Coupling = " << bin[3].num << endl;
   cout << " 5. Flange. Currently Number of Flange = " << bin[4].num << endl;
   cout << " 6. Gear. Currently Number of Gear = " << bin[5].num << endl;
   cout << " 7. Gear_Housing" << bin[6].num << endl;
   cout << " 8. Vacuum_Gripper" << bin[7].num << endl;
   cout << " 9. Cable. Currently Number of Cable = " << bin[8].num << endl;
   cout << " 10. Rod. Currently Number of Rod = " << bin[9].num << endl;    
   cout << " 11. Choose 11 to quit the Program" << endl;
```

}

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < Number_Bins; i++) { cout << Bin[i].description << ": " << Bin[i].num << endl; }`

Comment: that will take all the bins changing the number of parts of all of them.

Comment: I don't understand your question so I guessed.

Comment: Why not use std::map<std::string,int> instead of Inventory[]??? Code will be a lot less error prone and a lot easier to develop and read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you're asking how to pass one of the array elements to a function that adds or removes parts. You can do that by using a reference variable (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html).

For example, in your case, this function would remove a part:

```
void RemovePart(Inventory& part)
{
    if (part.num > 0)
        part.num -= 1;
    cout << part.description <<  " now has " << part.num << " parts." << endl;
}
```

Then you can call that function with an array element. For example, this removes a Bearing:

```
RemovePart(bin[1]);
```

Comment: in the program will ask how many parts the user wants to either remove or add. And the new result has to be shown in the list.